# Add watermark text to Excel document

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I'm using OpenXML to generate Excel file.

I want to add watermark text to the Excel sheet using OpenXML.

How I can do this using OpenXML?

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Follow this tutorial you will definitely get your desired output => [How to Add Watermark to Excel Sheet in C#, VB.NET](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Header-and-Footer/How-to-Add-Watermark-to-Excel-Sheet-in-C-VB.NET.html)

Comment: Create a template file with the watermark already there and open that each time...

Comment: In general, if you are using the OpenXML SDK, you should download & familiarize yourself with the OpenXML Productivity Tool, downloadable from Microsoft's site. If you create a spreadsheet in Excel, save it, and then add the one feature you are interested in (the watermark) and save that, you can open the two files in the tool and see the diffs in the reflected OpenXML code.

Answer (score 0):

As word document watermark there is no such feature in Microsoft excel. But it can be mimic by applying Header, Footer or background image.
Please refer below link for adding background image in E

[Add background image to Excel using OpenXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55040946/add-background-image-to-excel-using-openxml/66939875#66939875)