# Add background image to Excel using OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I'm using Open XML to create Excel. I want to add background image to the Excel. 
Don't tell me add image to excel and compare with OpenXML Productivity Tool.
Please let me know extract way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Post your code.

Comment: I don't have any idea on this. So I don't have code related to adding background image.

Comment: I noticed that this is not documented very well. If you truly NEED to do this then the following will help you along your way. Create a Word file with a image background and turn it into a ZIP file then research the document.xml in the word map. Includes in openXML are the same as the letter prefix in Word documents so w:Background would be Wordprocessing.DocumentBackground() for example.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.documentbackground?view=openxml-2.8.1

Answer (score 0):

I have dig into applying a background image to Excel using OpenXML and I am sharing code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //pathe of the Excel file to add background image
        string document = @"Book1.xlsx";
        // Open the document for editing.  
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(document, true))
        {
            //  Get existing sheets from workbook.  
            Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
            // Loop through all sheets and add image as background
            foreach (var sheet in sheets.Elements<Sheet>())
            {
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);
                CreateWorksheetPart(worksheetPart);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void CreateWorksheetPart(WorksheetPart part)
    {
        ImagePart imagePart1 = part.ImageParts.FirstOrDefault();
        if (imagePart1 == null)
            imagePart1 = part.AddNewPart<ImagePart>("image/jpeg", "rId1");
        string str = part.GetIdOfPart(imagePart1);
        GenerateImagePart1Content(imagePart1);
        GeneratePartContent(part, str);

    }
    private static void GenerateImagePart1Content(ImagePart imagePart1)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream("WatermarkDoc.png", FileMode.Open))
        {
            imagePart1.FeedData(stream);
        }
    }

    private static void GeneratePartContent(WorksheetPart part, string idPart)
    {
        Worksheet worksheet1 = part.Worksheet;
        Picture picture1 = new Picture() { Id = idPart };
        worksheet1.Append(picture1);
    }
}
```

Use the below tool to find out more classes in openXML.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425?